# lua write number and string in binary format to file?

Tags: lua, binary

I'd like to deserialize some lua tables to binary files. in c++ I can just use something like "fout << (char*)(&value)" where "value" is an integer or something else. but how to do this in lua? when I open a file with 'b' and write number and string to it they are quite readable in notepad...how can I convert lua values to binary format?

Comment: pardon my ignorance but what is a "binary data" actually? I used to think it as something more convenient than plain text data which is how numbers are stored in memory(in c++). but here it appears to be just another encoding method. and why we use it at all?

Comment: Simply because number `255`(unsigned char) in ASCII is `32 35 35`(16) but `FF`(16) in "binary".

Comment: so we write hexadecimal to file and call them "binary file"? nothing more than an encoding method?

Comment: Lua 5.3 has string.pack function. For preview versions you can use some other libraries e.g. struct or vstruct.